# Is $\min\limits_{x,y}\{\sqrt{1+x^2}-\sqrt{1-y^2}\mid C\}$ is convex problem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, positive-semidefinite

I need to understand if $$\min_{x,y}\left\{\sqrt{1+x^2}-\sqrt{1-y^2}\,\middle|\,\frac{\sqrt{(x-1)^{2}+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}}\leq\frac12,\ |y|\leq1\right\}$$is convex problem. I found that the domain$$C=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\,\middle|\,\frac{\sqrt{(x-1)^{2}+y^{2}}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{x^{2}+(y-2)^{2}}}}\leq\mu\right\} \cap\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\,\middle|\,|y|\le1\right\}$$ is convex and I need to figure out if $f\left(\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\right)=\sqrt{1+x^{2}}-\sqrt{1-y^{2}}$ is a convex function in that domain.

I found the gradient of $f$ is: $$\nabla f\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}\right)\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\\
\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}
\end{array}\right)$$ and the hessian of f is $$\nabla^{2}f\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}\right)\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}-\frac{x^{2}}{\left(\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\right)^{3}} & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}+\frac{y^{2}}{\left(\sqrt{1-y^{2}}\right)^{3}}
\end{array}\right)$$

I want to show that the hessian is not psd and therefor $f$ is not convex,but I don't rellay sure how to do that..

Thanks!!!

Comment: The Hessian is psd. Make the common denominator to see that.

Comment: I Done just that ..why $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\right)^{3}} & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{1-y^{2}}\right)^{3}}
\end{array}\right)$$ but why is a psd matrix?
it's because the eigenvalues of this matrix are $$\begin{cases}
\lambda_{1}=\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\right)^{3}}\\
\lambda_{2}=\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{1-y^{2}}\right)^{3}}
\end{cases}$$  (non-negative numbers)?

Comment: Yes, and it is easy to see by definition of psd.